# Getting role based on only User Id in Moodle 3.0

Tags: moodle

Currently in my system we have 4 roles : course admin, trainer, student, corporate user.

Once login we need to redirect to custom Dashboard where we will display custom functionalities.

So I'm wondering how we can implement that considering we have only user id.

I got option based on course

```
$coursecontext = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE, $course->id);

if (!has_capability('moodle/course:viewhiddensections', $coursecontext)) {

echo "is Student<br/>";
}
```

But in my case we have only user id. How we can implement this? I hope Moodle is not so complicated to do such small check.

Answer (score 0):

You can check any user's capability by passing a 3rd argument to `has_capability`.

```
if (!has_capability('moodle/course:viewhiddensections', $coursecontext, $userid)) {
    ...
}
```

Note that with Moodle 3.0 you should be getting the context using:

```
$context = context_course::instance($courseid);
```

If you are not in the context of a course, the roles then need to be assigned in the system context. To get the system context you can use `context_system::instance()`.

Lastly, if you are assigning your roles individually in each course and not in the system (which I suspect you do), there is no easy way to determine what type of user has logged in. In that case all users will be the same until they get in a course. To dermine the roles of the user you would have to check each course context individually.

If in your scenario a user cannot be `student` in course A and `trainer` in course B, then you could add all your students in a cohort `Student`, and do the same for each other role. On login you could then check what cohort they are in. You may even be able to use the *Cohort sync* enrolment plugin so that you don't have to manage the enrolments anymore.